# bitcoin-qt wont launch after 4 hours

Tags: bitcoin-core

I decided to run a full node recently, as I want to import keys to a new wallet.
However, the program wont open while running a full node.

Started synching yesterday at morning, it synched up to 2018.
Closed the program, turned off the computer, went to sleep.
Waked up today, turned on the computer, opened the program.
Four hours have passed, software is stuck on "verifying blocks, press Q to close" initial screen.
I killed the process as it was only at 20% of "verifying", so I noticed it won't open for the entire day.

While pruned, it takes longer to synch, but program opens in a matter of seconds.
Why this is happening? I remember it took 30 minutes to open a full node in 2020, and that's why I switched to pruned.
But four hours?
How do I avoid the initial "verification"?

I'm using a EVO 870 SSD, and my processor is a i5 8400, with 32gb of RAM.

Comment: I'm trying it again. Yesterday the blockchain synched up to 20 minutes left before fully synched. I turned the PC off, went to sleep. 
Turned it on now, and the program is stuck in the initial screen. 
It says "re-veryfing blocks" and 0%. Its been an hour since I launched it. 

https://imgur.com/p4t0PZp

Answer (score 0):

> **How do I avoid the initial "verification"?**

As I understand it, you can't avoid the initial verification because Bitcoin core needs to check the integrity of its data in order to protect you from financial harm.